# Facebox beforeClose confirmation

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Facebox in a project and in the facebox there is a textarea.

I am having trouble keeping the Facebox open if the user clicks cancel on a confirmation box which is trigger beforeClose.facebox.

I have the beforeClose.facebox working but if I click the cancel button on the confirmation box it still closes facebox. If I click cancel, I would like the Facebox to stay open.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have this same problem, hopefully someone will have a solution someday.